# Write query to parse HTML DOCUMENT with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, linq, html-agility-pack

I want to get the A href of that element in **span class="floatClear"**  whose rating is minimum in
**span class="star-img stars_4"**

How can I use HtmlAgilityPack to achieve this behaviour I have give the html source of my file

```
<div class="businessresult">  //will repeat


      <div class="rightcol">

       <div class="rating">

        <span class="star-img stars_4">
          <img height="325" width="84" src="http://media1.px" alt="4.0 star rating"   **title**="4.0 star rating">
         </span>

        </div>
      </div>

        <span class="floatClear">
             <a class="ybtn btn-y-s" href="/writeareview/biz/KaBw8UEm8u6war_loc%NY">
        </span>
</div>
```

The query I have written

```
var lowestreview = 
      from main in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='rightcol']") 
       from rating in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='rating']")
         from ratingspan in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='star-img stars_4']")
          from floatClear in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='floatClear']")
       select new { Rate = ratingspan.InnerText, AHref = floatClear.InnerHtml };
```

But I do not know how to apply condition here at last line of LINQ query!

Comment: Are you sure this is the right query? You are selecting a bunch of *independant* nodes: You get all "rating" divs whether or not they are withing a "rightcol" div (and so on).

Comment: I am not sure that,s why i am asking!

Comment: Does it has to be in one query?

Comment: not necessary i just need to parse the html and get url of the lowest reviewed product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't select "rating" from the entire htmlDoc, select it from the previously found "main".

I guess you need something like:

```
var lowestreview = 
  from main in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='rightcol']") 
   from rating in main.SelectNodes("//div[@class='rating']")
     from ratingspan in rating.SelectNodes("//span[@class='star-img stars_4']")
      from floatClear in ratingspan.SelectNodes("//span[@class='floatClear']")
   select new { Rate = ratingspan.InnerText, AHref = floatClear.InnerHtml };
```

I hope it will not crash if some of those divs ans spans are not present: a previous version of the HtmlAgilityPack returned null instead of an empty list when the `SelectNodes` didn't find anything.

EDIT
You probably also need to change the "xpath query" for the inner selects: change the "//" into ".//" (extra . at the beginning) to signal that you really want a subnode. If the AgilityPack works the same as regular XML-XPath (I'm not 100% sure) then a "//" at the beginning will search from the root of the document, even if you specify it from a subnode. A ".//" will always search from the node you are searching from.

A `main.SelectNodes("//div[@class='rating']")` will (probably) also find `<div class="rating">`s outside the `<div class="rightcol">` you found in the previous line.
A `main.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='rating']")` should fix that.

Comment: I think 2nd last line should be  from floatClear in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='floatClear']")  //as floatclear is not sub node of rightcol div.Also in EDIT you mention to replace the // with what is it (.//)