# How can I query a text file for distinct instances of a pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I am creating documents (see [this](http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/)) that contain any number of characters (human characters/voices), like so:

```
<span class="sam" title="This is Sam speaking">
<span class="higbie" title="This is Calvin Higbie speaking">
<span class="ballou" title="This is Mr. Ballou speaking">
```

For some context, here is a snippet of a document:

```
  <p><span class="others" title="This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking">"Jack, do you see that range of mountains over yonder that bounds the Jordan valley?  The mountains of Moab, Jack!  Think of it, my
  boy--the actual mountains of Moab--renowned in Scripture history!
  We are actually standing face to face with those illustrious crags
  and peaks--and for all we know" [dropping his voice impressively],
  "our eyes may be resting at this very moment upon the spot WHERE
  LIES THE MYSTERIOUS GRAVE OF MOSES!  Think of it, Jack!"</span></p>
```

When a document is complete, I would like to generate a distinct list of this pattern of markup. IOW, I want to examine every piece of HTML that follows that pattern, but only return one instance of each distinct person/speaker. I don't want 400 of these:

```
<span class="sam" title="This is Sam speaking">
```

...(just one).

In pseudo-SQL terminoloy, what I want is something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SOMETHING FROM FILE WHERE SLIDING_WINDOW_OF_TEXT STARTSWITH("<span class=\"") AND SLIDING_WINDOW_OF_TEXT ENDSWITH("  speaking\">")
```

I don't know if this is something best attacked using regex, or if there's something like a "LinqToText", or something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that hard. You may use `LINQ` to get `Distinct()` values. Add references and `using System.Linq;`/`using System.Xml.Linq;`. Here is a working sample (tested in VS2012):

```
var MyRegex = new Regex(@"(?i)<span class=([""']).+?\1 title=([""']).+?\2>", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var str = @"<p><span class=""others"" title=""This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking""><span class=""others"" title=""This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking""><span class=""others"" title=""This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking""><span class=""others"" title=""This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking""><span class=""higbie"" title=""This is Calvin Higbie speaking""><span class=""ballou"" title=""This is Mr. Ballou speaking""><span class=""ballou"" title=""This is Mr. Ballou speaking""><span class=""higbie"" title=""This is Calvin Higbie speaking""></p>";
var distinct_values = MyRegex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Returns 3 (not 8) matches:

[image]

[**NO-LINQ SOLUTION**](http://goo.gl/SLeYu2)

In case you cannot use LINQ (e.g. in Mono), you can use the following code that leverages `List<string>` from `System.Collections.Generic`:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var MyRegex = new Regex(@"(?i)<span class=([""']).+?\1 title=([""']).+?\2>", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var str = @"<p><span class=""others"" title=""This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking""><span class=""others"" title=""This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking""><span class=""others"" title=""This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking""><span class=""others"" title=""This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking""><span class=""higbie"" title=""This is Calvin Higbie speaking""><span class=""ballou"" title=""This is Mr. Ballou speaking""><span class=""ballou"" title=""This is Mr. Ballou speaking""><span class=""higbie"" title=""This is Calvin Higbie speaking""></p>";
  //      var distinct_values = MyRegex.Matches(str).
//                    Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).Distinct().ToList();
        var new_arr = new List<string>();
        var matches = MyRegex.Matches(str);
        for (int i=0; i<matches.Count; i++)
            if (!new_arr.Contains(matches[i].Value))
               new_arr.Add(matches[i].Value);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", new_arr));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<span class="others" title="This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking">                                                                                                 
<span class="higbie" title="This is Calvin Higbie speaking">                                                                                                        
<span class="ballou" title="This is Mr. Ballou speaking">
```

Comment: "Not that hard" when you've got Regex and LINQ down like a champ, and know how to use them, but the average person's head would explode into tiny splinters and fluffy stuff on looking at that code.

Comment: I get, "'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
Right-clicking "Cast" affords no "Resolve" context menu item...

Comment: Please add `System.Linq`, `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Text.RegularExpressions` statements to the list of `using` directives. Also, it is possible that you need to add the reference to your project (right-click the `References` node in your project, click **Add Reference** go to `Framwork` tab and check if `System.Xml.Linq` is selected).

Comment: It had semi-automatically added the latter; why it didn't prompt for the first two is a mystery and a tad irksome.

Comment: I have added a non-LINQ solution to the answer: you can check it out at http://goo.gl/SLeYu2.

Comment: It works just fine after adding those usings. What irked me was that VS didn't know what was needed - it should, shouldn't it? I will give you the bounty ASAP (tomorrow).

Comment: From what I know, Visual Studio does not automatically add `using` statements. However, you can make Visual Studio provide you a hint: place the cursor on the underlined line of code, and hit **SHIFT+ALT+F10**: a context menu will appear with suggested using statements.

Comment: I simply right-click on the squiggled line; normally, it *does* work (I get a "Resolve" option in the context menu). This time, though, it didn't. That's why I threw a temper tantrum and ripped the life-sized poster of Justin Bieber from the neighboring cubicle to shreds.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which would let you query html. Here's an example: ([Write query to parse HTML DOCUMENT with HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275200/how-to-write-query-to-parse-html-document-with-htmlagilitypack).)

You may also be able to use LinqToXml to query the html elements as xml nodes.