# How can I use OrderBy<> in my LINQified Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, linq-to-objects

I found out how to extract distinct elements from an html file here
[How can I query a text file for distinct instances of a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401625/how-can-i-query-a-text-file-for-distinct-instances-of-a-pattern)

...and the results are good. I get (truncated):

```
<span class="sam" title="This is Sam Clemens speaking">
<span class="others" title="This is 'The Sphynx' speaking">
<span class="others" title="This is the stagecoach driver speaking">
<span class="others" title="This is someone other than the main characters speaking">
<span class="others" title="The station-boss is speaking">
<span class="others" title="This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking">
<span class="others2" title="This is Jack speaking">
<span class="bemis" title="This is Bemis speaking">
```

I would like to sort these, though, so that the above is:

```
<span class="bemis" title="This is Bemis speaking">
<span class="sam" title="This is Sam Clemens speaking">
<span class="others" title="The station-boss is speaking">
<span class="others" title="This is 'an elderly pilgrim' speaking">
<span class="others" title="This is 'The Sphynx' speaking">
<span class="others" title="This is someone other than the main characters speaking">
<span class="others" title="This is the stagecoach driver speaking">
<span class="others2" title="This is Jack speaking">
```

This line of code:

```
distinct_values = MyRegex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

...gets the data as shown first. I assume I need to do something like this:

```
distinct_values = MyRegex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).Distinct().OrderBy<>
```

...but even if I'm right, I don't know what should be within the angle brackets of the OrderBy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle brackets? Nothing, that will be inferred. It's the argument that's important:

```
.OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

Of course, it only works as expected because sorting by the whole string is good enough here. If not, you might want to select both the actual string, and another capture group which only has e.g. the `class` value.

Answer (score 1):

its the same as Select:

```
 .OrderBy(p => p.PropertyName)
```

where PropteryName is the name of the property you want to order by it.

if you want the return value as List then:

```
  .OrderBy(p => p.PropertyName).ToList();
```

in your case since its not an object but string then:

```
  .OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```